# Computing Hausdorff Distance for 2 images?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

So I have 2 images I am reading into matlab -- they are 2 pictures of letters, say the letter "A". One is a computer generated one, and the other is one that a person drew. I can get the binary vector for them or a list of (X,Y) coordinates from these images. Let say they are each about [100,100] sized vectors.

I want to know how well the human drew the image based on how close the letters are to each other using the Hausdorff Distance. There is code in matlab that does this (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26738-hausdorff-distance)

But I confused on if it is even possible to compute this and what a low or high value would mean?

Answer (score 1):

Hausdorff distance is an extremely  crude measure for the "closeness" of images.  Suppose $p_1$ and $p_2$ are points of sets 1 and 2 respectively whose distance is $r$, $p_2$ being the closest point to $p_1$ in set 2, while all other points in set 1 are within distance $r$ of set 2 and all points in set 2 are within distance $r$ of set 1.  Then the Hausdorff distance between the two sets is $r$.  The other points in set 1 can be moved around arbitrarily as long as they stay within distance $r$ of set 2, and the other points of set 2 can be moved arbitrarily as long as they stay within distance $r$ of set 1 but no closer than $r$ to $p_1$, and it won't affect the Hausdorff distance at all.

Comment: In the OP's application, the correspondence (between pairs of points) is fuzzy at best, so his confusion is understandble.